# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am working with EBS payment gateway .I have attached EBS sdk as new module and added project as library.But while building i am getting the following issue.More specifically Issue i am getting is

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 3.072 secs Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in console "
```

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mylaw.rkme3.mylawproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

ext {
    gsonLibVersion = "2.6.1"
    okHttpLibVersion = "2.7.5"
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile project(':EBS')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
```

Comment: you are not showing us gradle please put it here

Comment: ohh Sorry will edit and post that soon